# How can I hide/close NSWindowController and its view?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I want to hide the view with an option to show it again later.
I use showWindow to make window visible. How do i make the window invisible?

Answer (score 2):

[`-[NSWindow orderOut:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000013-BCIBHEIE)